# Do conductors reflect Wifi signals? If so why?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, conductors, microwaves

I know electric field can't pass through conductors, but I have seen people surround their wifi router by soda can (not entirely) for better signal strength. I want to know what really happens there.

Comment: [Is it possible to “boost” a WiFi signal using an aluminium soda can](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3358/is-it-possible-to-boost-a-wifi-signal-using-an-aluminum-soda-can)

Comment: Without a picture or a link, it's hard to answer for sure, but there are a lot of examples on the internet of people using metal reflectors to try to boost a WiFi connection. Since multiple, interfering reflections in a realistic room or home complicate the situation, it's often random chance if the reflector hurts or helps a specific connection, but Im sure playing around with it a while, some metal reflectors behind the router's antenna might *sometimes* improve a connection for one specific WiFi user.